# What causes "failed to connect to server: File name too long" error when I try to use tmux

Tags: ssh, server, tmux

I can ssh into the server fine. Then when I try to tmux attach to my old session I get this error, I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: Command line(s) used, any specifics of you `tmux` setup and state?

Comment: bash, command is just "tmux", this is on Centos

Comment: "File name too long" seems clear enough. What do you not understand?

Comment: What file? I am creating a session or attaching to one, what file is being referenced here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the TMPDIR - before this was a very long path that tmux was looking for, I changed it to a more local one and the problem was fixed. My misunderstanding stemmed from lack of knowledge about how TMUX works - apparently the session data is stored in TMPDIR or TMUX_TMPDIR, and when the path to these are too long, the resulting filename is also too long, giving the error in question.